# pandas with csv file: displaying a descending count list of which items of column 1 that has the most of 3 specific items of column 2

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I'm trying out pandas here... i read on how powerful and useful is it recently, so i'm giving it a go! Trying out some combos here and there, and I'm stuck with this one:

Let's say I've got a csv file that has the following 2 columns:

**name**: one name can be displayed multiple times

**food**: can either be banana, apple, carrot, celery or potato.

The same person can have the same food multiple times.

The table looks like this:

| name | food |
| --- | --- |
| paul | carrot |
| paul | potato |
| paul | apple |
| alex | banana |
| alex | celery |
| marie | potato |
| marie | apple |
| paul | apple |
| carl | potato |
| ... | ... |
| bob | banana |

I need a descending list going from the person who has the most vegetables to the person who has the least vegetables along with how much they have in total.

The nearest result I got is with the following script where I tried to only display the vegetables:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('foodcounter.csv')

s = df['name'].groupby(df['food']).value_counts()[['carrot','potato','celery']]

print(s.to_string())
```

The output looks like this:

| food | name | count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| carrot | paul | 43 |
|  | alex | 32 |
|  | carl | 13 |
|  | ... | ... |
| celery | Paul | 12 |
|  | alex | 3 |
|  | marie | 1 |
|  | ... | ... |
| potato | paul | 33 |
|  | marie | 23 |
|  | alex | 14 |

The output i'm aiming for is this (names + count from biggest amount to the smallest amount):

| name | count |
| --- | --- |
| Paul | 88 |
| alex | 77 |
| marie | 66 |
| ... | ... |
| carl | 16 |
| bob | 5 |
| john | 1 |

You can see paul has the most vegetables, followed by alex and marie.

John has the least vegetables.

The total for paul is 88. That was the addition of all of paul's carrots/potatoes/celeries.

Same goes for alex, marie, etc.

I'm pretty sure i'm either very close or i need a completely new aproach on this..

Let me know :)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it not long ago. I decided to share the code here!

I started by moving all the line with vegetables to another csv file named foodcounter.csv:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('foodcounter.csv')

df2 = (df["food"]=="carrots") | \
      (df["food"]=="porato") | \
      (df["food"]=="celery")

s = df[df2]

s.to_csv(r'vegetablesonly.csv', index = None, header=True)
```

Using the new csv file, i used this command to show the output i needed:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('vegetablesonly.csv')

s = df['food'].value_counts()

print(s.to_string())
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what you have done, take `s` and:

```
s.groupby("name").sum().sort_values(ascending=False)
```

Comment: yeah... i tried something like that before. I still get the food in the first column like in the second table i made above. As you can see, there are fruits and vegetables. I only need the sum of how many vegetables they have in total, an sort the names from the most to the least vegetables. I think i'm using this bit wrong:
`groupby(df['food']).value_counts()[['carrot','potato','celery']]` Today, i've been trying to "where condition" my way to doing it.


Thanks for the quick reply by the way!

Comment: If you want to only include a specific set of food items in the sum, use `.query` to select the correct rows:

`veggies = ["carrot", "potato"]
df.groupby("food").value_counts().reset_index().query("food in @veggies").groupby("name").sum(numeric_only=True).sort_values(by=0, ascending=False)`